# Read all section .ini values into stringgrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

I use Delphi XE7. Is there any way to load all values from an .ini file into a stringgrid in different coloumns?

My .ini file looks like

```
[1038]
AValue = a1 
BValue = b1
CValue = c1
DValue = d1

[1031]
AValue = a2 
BValue = b2
CValue = c2
DValue = d2
```

I use this procedure for filling the grid:

```
procedure TForm1.ReadIntoGrid(const aIniFileName, aSection: string;
const aGrid: TStringGrid);
var
  Ini: TIniFile;
  SL: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Ini := TIniFile.Create(aIniFileName);
    try
      aGrid.ColCount := 2;
      Ini.ReadSectionValues(aSection, SL);
      aGrid.RowCount := SL.Count;

      for i := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do
      begin
        aGrid.Cells[0,i] := SL.Names[i];
        aGrid.Cells[1,i] := SL.ValueFromIndex[i];
      end;
    finally
      Ini.Free;
    end;
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It works fine, I get this:

[image]

My question is...
How can I read all section values (1038 and 1031) into the grid next to the 1038 values? Values will be fixed all time.

[image]

Comment: What part of this task are you finding difficult. On the face of it you appear to know how to read from INI files, and how to work with string grids. It seems like you have all you need.

Comment: I have to agree with David here. The only tricky part seems to synchronize the item names of the different sections into the string grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give you some ideas:

First, i think you should add one paramater to your procedure:

```
procedure TForm1.ReadIntoGrid(const aIniFileName, aSection: string;
const aGrid: TStringGrid; const aColumn: Integer = 1);
```

Second, rewrite this part of your method :

```
  for i := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do
  begin
    aGrid.Cells[0,i] := SL.Names[i];
    aGrid.Cells[1,i] := SL.ValueFromIndex[i];
  end;
```

replace with

```
  for i := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do
  begin
    aGrid.Cells[0,i] := SL.Names[i];
    aGrid.Cells[aColumn,i] := SL.ValueFromIndex[i];
  end;
```

ps: Obviously you dont nead to rewrite the value into the first column.

So now assume you are calling the method like this:

```
ReadIntoGrid('MyIniFile.ini','1038', MyGrid, 1);
ReadIntoGrid('MyIniFile.ini','1031', MyGrid, 2);
```

Comment: That might fail if the items inside the sections are different or in a different order.

Comment: Yes, it is assuming that we comparing sames items

Comment: Suggestion: `aGrid.Rows(0).BeginUpdate; try ReadIntoGrid(...); ReadIntoGrid(...); finally aGrid.Rows(0).EndUpdate end;` to reduce flicker and add some speed